# How to measure/know the moles of carbon dioxide (as dry ice) when in KOH solution

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, home-experiment

I am doing an experiment where I am dropping dry ice in a $\ce{KOH}$ solution. I want to know how I can figure out how many moles of $\ce{CO2}$ reacted with the $\ce{KOH}$. I am pouring $25 \,\mathrm{g}$ of $\ce{KOH}$ in $100 \,\mathrm{mL}$ of water and I am using $50 \,\mathrm{g}$ of dry ice. The experiment is conducted at room temperature.

I know one way to do this is by isolating the product of $\ce{K2CO3}$ but because $\ce{K2CO3}$ is soluble, it is going to be very hard to isolate this product and weight it and use simple stoichiometry to figure out the moles of $\ce{CO2}$ reacted.

I was thinking maybe the pH meter will help but again, I do not know how to use the pH to calculate how many moles of carbon dioxide reacted.

#### Observations

During experimentation, I saw the pH decreased when I added the $\ce{CO2}$.Will this fact be useful to calculate moles of $\ce{K2CO3}$ formed? The pH decreased from 13 to 10.

Can someone please help?

Comment: weigh-difference of the solution from before and after adding $CO_2$ and letting it react?

Comment: The pH meter will only help if you know there is some direct correlation between the addition of $CO_2$ and the pH of the solution during the reaction.  Do you know definitively if this is the case?

Comment: No I do not I was only guessing that CO2 in solution behaves as acid so maybe there might be an increase in pH

Comment: @Fl.pf. wouldn't there be conversation of mass

Comment: @user510 Yes? But that has nothing to do with anyhting here.

You have 100 ml of water with 25 ml KOH = 100g + how much 25 g KOH weighs.

After it has reacted with the CO2 you have 100 ml Water + rest KOH + K2CO3 - whatever leaves the reaction. Then you can easily calculate how much CO2 reacted..

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case weighing would work with limited accuracy (I am going to explain the limitations later in the answer).

Since the only compound leaving the reaction is the unreacted $\ce{CO2}$, it is valid to use weighing. Everything else is either sticking around or is already included in the initial weighing. So by weighing everything prior to reaction and after "all unreacted $\ce{CO2}$ is vaporized", you can calculate the amount of "reacted $\ce{CO2}$".

(weight of reacted $\ce{CO2}$) = (Weight of initial $\ce{CO2}$) - (weight of unreacted $\ce{CO2}$)

(Weight of initial $\ce{CO2}$) = (50 g) - (condensed water from atmosphere [estimate])

(Weight of unreacted $\ce{CO2}$) = (deficit in pre vs post reaction weighing)

pre reaction weight: 50 g $\ce{CO2}$ + 25 g $\ce{KOH}$ +100 g water = 175 g

post reaction weight: weight of the whole solution after all unreacted $\ce{CO2}$ is escaped from the solution (make sure the whole solution is at room temperature and make sure there is no bubbling occurring).

I understand there are some practical limitations, mainly :

1- There might be unreacted/frozen $\ce{CO2}$ still hanging around, Try to shake well. Also when weighing post reaction, make sure your solution is slightly warm to assist unreacted $\ce{CO2}$ to evaporate fully from the reaction.

2-Since you have dry ice, some water from atmosphere will condense into your reaction, this will lead to underestimation of the "leaving compound". The way to overcome, is to keep your reaction vessel as small as possible and control its inlet by a cold trap to make sure no water from atmosphere gets in. Also account for amount of water usually present in 50 g dry ice, by examining the water content on a similar sample beforehand.

pH:
Your initial pH is clearly not right. concentration of your $\ce{OH-}$ is way higher than just 0.1 M. Let's assume that it is due to high pH value being out of the calibration range of the pH-meter and let's assume that your pH=10 after addition of $\ce{CO2}$ is correct.

One will be able to calculate the amount of unreacted $\ce{CO2}$ from reaction balance. You are starting with 25 g (0.446 moles) of $\ce{KOH}$ and 50 g (1.14 moles) of $\ce{CO2}$. For every $\ce{CO2}$ reacting, 2 $\ce{KOH}$ are used up. So IF all(or most) of $\ce{KOH}$ is used up, you should end up with 0.446/2~ 0.22 moles of $\ce{K2CO3}$, which means the reacted CO2 is about 0.22 moles(~9.7 g), and unreacted is 0.92 moles(~40.3 g). 
Why do I make the assumption that all the $\ce{KOH}$ is reacted, notice your final pH is 10 , meaning that your [OH-] concentration is about 0.0001 M, your starting concentration was 4.4 M.

What stops the reaction from using all $\ce{KOH}$ to be used up and dropping the pH to neutral zone? You are using excess $\ce{CO2}$, so we expect all the $\ce{KOH}$ to be used up. This has to do with part of $\ce{CO2}$ escaping the reaction as gas, also since the temperature is freezing the water (by dry ice) you may not have complete agitation which hinders the reaction procession to some extent.

I still think that you should take the weighing method seriously. Using weighing methods will provide confirmation for your calculations.

Comment: so you want me to evaporate the solution. I do not get how I will weight "evaporation of all unreacted CO2"

Comment: No no, don't evaporate the whole solution. Just letting the sit and reach room temperature will make most of the CO2 to evaporate.

Comment: i edited my question after i saw some observation when i did the experiment. Can you let me know if the observations help to go the pH way?

Comment: The pH should decrease after the CO2 addition, right? so please edit the question again. I will put up something for calculation.

Comment: i did: it went from 13 pH to 10

Comment: In the observation part please change "pH increased" to "pH decreased", first sentence. I added the calculation in the answer based on CO2 being in excess.

Comment: i thought more of the CO2 would react under a lower temperature?

Comment: The theoretical maximum for CO2 is about 0.223 moles, there would not be any KOH beyond that to react with CO2. Your starting KOH is 0.446 moles, and each CO2 molecule reacts with two molecules of KOH to make one K2CO3 molecule. No matter what the temperature is, it would bot be possible for CO2 to react beyond 0.223 moles.

Comment: is there a way to back calculate from moles of Co2 in solution (which you said was 0.22 moles) to what the pH should be of the KOH + CO2 reaction?

Comment: I meant the theoretically maximum amount of CO2 that would react is 0.223 moles. That is because the amount of KOH is 0.446, and CO2 can not react more than half of that amount. And theoretically there should be a way to back calculate remaining CO2 in the solution from pH. But since your pH is very basic (10), I don't see any such calculation to be reliable. Since you are starting with very high concentration of KOH, it makes things difficult. If you start with low KOH and a pH of about 8-9 and then drop the pH by adding CO2 to lower than 7 , then it would be possible to do that.

Comment: Right now, pH is still so basic that makes any CO2 react and make K2CO3, effectively eliminating the possibility of any existence of unreacted CO2 inside the solution.

Comment: okay, so you said that the initial weight accounts for all the reactants and products, I am not sure if that is true. My initial weight is just KOH and water. My final weight I would measure would be the KOH+CO2 reaction weight. Could you please explain why the initial weight includes the weight of K2CO3 and produced water. Also, wouldn't the post minus pre reaction weighting give me the weight of CO2 reacted?

Comment: I revised the answer to address your points. By pre reaction weight, I meant the weight of everything before the mixing. The reason I broke it down like above was to account for condensed water on dry ice. If you exclude CO2 from initial weighing and wait long enough for all unreacted CO2 to evaporate and then weight post reaction, then yes: post minus pre reaction (without 50 g CO2 weight) would be weight of reacted CO2.